# Dynamically increase UIView Height when Tableview Height get Increased Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

[image]

I have Implemented tableview named as mytableview inside `UIView` in `UITableviewController` named as maintablevew,and also I dynamically increased mytableview height based on cells count.it getting Increased Dynamically,Here my problem is when mytableview height getting increased I can't scroll upto bottom because I can't increased UIView height Dynamically,I don't know how to increase,can anyone suggest? Below code I used to increase mytableview height Dynamically.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    CGFloat numberOfRows =roomlabel.count;

    CGRect tableViewFrame = tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = numberOfRows * _mytableview.rowHeight;
    _mytableview.frame = tableViewFrame;

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Comment: add a height constraint to your view, create a IBOutlet to  height constraint and finally update the constraint's constant value to `numberOfRows * _mytableview.rowHeight;` finally call `layoutIfNeeded` on your view to reflect constraint value change

Comment: ok let I check and where would I call layoutIfNeeded method ....can send the sample code for this issues.

Comment: Share your requirement screen shot. Because if you set the frame(with all cells heights) to UITableView, then all cells are think they are in visible state. Then how can they scroll?. So embedded your table view in inside scroll view.

Comment: I uploaded my screenload...Bottom i have a cell, but I can't able to scroll

Comment: Is that UIView subview of Cell in UITableViewController , where you have added the myTableView?

Comment: yes UIView is subview of cell in uitableviewcontroller and I added mytableview inside of uiview

Comment: email no and mobile number are textfields, bottom I have designed UItableview

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to increase(change) the height of the UITableView or UIView, You just have to provide cell height, It will automatically update it's content size, and table will become scrollable.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
CGFloat numberOfRows =roomlabel.count;
return numberOfRows; }
```

Comment: first I used this code to populate array values but when I scroll the tableview the top values are getting hide for that I increased my tableview height dynamically?? and if I increase my view height also means it works perfect ,I don't know how to do that,.....